# Testing Angular $q qith Jasmine 2 and karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Trying to test a promise based service which does something like this:

```
load : function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //Do misc async stuff
        deferred.resolve();

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

When trying to test this in Karma + Jasmine 2.0 I try to use its done() callbacks but it always times out and does not ever resolve the promise.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    service = $injector.get('myService');
    $window = $injector.get("$window");
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
}));

describe('Call load', function () {
    it('resolves its promise', function (done) {
      service.load().then(function(){
          expect(something).not.toBe(undefined);
          done();
      });
    });
});
```

From Jasmines docs this is how I though you should use done() along with async code, but seems the problem is that the promise never resolves

Comment: $scope.$apply() should resolve the promises

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns. You should make that an answer.

Comment: Thanks @TimCastlijns, I agree with others you should make that an answer with an explanation. The issue of unresolved promises in unit tests had me baffled for quite some time.

Comment: Added an answer since I almost glossed right past this question since it had no answer and it's been over two years.

Answer (score 0):

As @TimCastelijns mentioned in the comments, you need to call `$scope.$apply` to resolve the promises in your unit tests:

```
load: function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function () {
        //Do misc async stuff
        deferred.resolve();
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why do you need to call `$scope.$apply()` to resolve a promise. What if I don't use `$scope`? What if I return an existed promise such as `$http.get()`?